# Can Execution Time be set in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an application leveraging Entity Framework 6. For queries that are relatively fast (e.g. taking less than a minute to execute) it is working fine.

But I have a stored procedure that queries a table which doesn't have appropriate indices and so the time taken to execute the query has been clocked to take anywhere between 55 and 63 seconds. Obviously, indexing the table would bring that time down but unfortunately I don't have the luxury of controlling the situation and have to deal the hand I was dealt.

What I am seeing is when EF6 is used to call the stored procedure it continues through the code in less than 3 seconds total time and returns a result of 0 records; when I know there are 6 records the SPROC will return when executed directly in the database.

There are no errors whatsoever, so the code is executing fine.

Performing a test; I constructed some code using the SqlClient library and made the same call and it returned 6 records. Also noted that unlike the EF6 execution, that it actually took a few more seconds as if it were actually waiting to receive a response.

Setting the CommandTimeout on the context doesn't appear to make any difference either and I suspect possibly because it isn't timing out but rather not waiting for the result before it continues through the code?

I don't recall seeing this behavior in prior versions but then again maybe the time required to execute my prior queries were within the expected range of EF???

Is there a way to set the actual time that EF will wait for a response before continuing through the code? Or is there a way that I can enforce an asynchronous operation since it seems to be a default synchronous task by default?? Or is there a potential flaw in the code?

Sample of Code exhibiting (synchronous) execution: No errors but no records returned

```
public static List<Orphan> GetOrphanItems()
{
  try
    {
      using (var ctx = new DBEntities(_defaultConnection))
      {
         var orphanage =  from orp in ctx.GetQueueOrphans(null)
                          select orp;
         var orphans = orphanage.Select(o => new Orphan
                      {
                          ServiceQueueId = o.ServiceQueueID,
                          QueueStatus = o.QueueStatus,
                          OrphanCode = o.OrphanCode,
                          Status = o.Status,
                          EmailAddress = o.EmailAddress,
                          TemplateId = o.TemplateId
                      }).ToList();
         return orphans;
      }
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        // Handle the error
    }
}
```

Sample Code using SqlClient Library (asynchronous) takes slightly longer to execute but returns 6 records

```
public static List<Orphan> GetOrphanItems()
{
  long ServiceQueueId = 0;
  bool QueueStatus;
  var OrphanCode = String.Empty;
  DateTime Status;
  var EmailAddress = String.Empty;
  int TemplateId = 0;
  var orphans = new List<Orphan> ();
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_defaultConnection);   
  try
    {   
      var cmdText = "EXEC dbo.GetQueueOrphans";
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
      conn.Open();
      SqlDataReader reader;
      reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      while(reader.Read())
        {
          long.TryParse(reader["ServiceQueueId"].ToString(), out ServiceQueueId);
          bool.TryParse(reader["QueueStatus"].ToString(), out QueueStatus);
          OrphanCode = reader["OrphanCode"].ToString();
          DateTime.TryParse(reader["Status"].ToString(), out Status);
          EmailAddress = reader["EmailAddress"].ToString();
          int.TryParse(reader["TemplateId"].ToString(), out TemplateId);

          orphans.Add(new Orphan { ServiceQueueId = ServiceQueueId, QueueStatus=QueueStatus, OrphanCode=OrphanCode,
          EmailAddress=EmailAddress, TemplateId=TemplateId});
        }
      conn.Close();
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        // Handle the error
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the timeout in the connection string?

Comment: I have set it in the connection string as well as directly on the context. The results are the same

Comment: @Mark, are you sure your call it the same way with the same parameters?  Did you run SQL Profiler to make sure?

Comment: @johnny5, I didn't run SQL Profiler but I did inspect the context to affirm that the connection, settings and etc. were correct. The procedure doesn't require parameters

Comment: can you post the code on how you are calling the stored procedure

Comment: @johnny5 code posted

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of executing method.

```
private async void MyMethod()
{
db.executeProdecudeAsync(); 
}
```

Forgetting to await task in async void method can cause described behavior without any InteliSense warning.
Fix:

```
  private async Task MyMethod()
  {
    await db.executeProdecudeAsync(); 
  }
```

Or just use `db.executeProdecudeAsync().Wait()` if you want to run in synchronous mode.

Comment: I'll give your suggestion a try and will update the result

Comment: just prior to trying your suggestion I noted the use of what I guess you're referring to as the async version of the procedure? If I'm correct on that; there is no async version of my procedure and so the .Wait() method is unavailable as well. I've posted some sample code of what I have. I think you're on to something but I'm not certain how I'd implement invoking asynchronous calls on the procedure.